# Time Complexity of remove method of Set

Tags: java, collections, set

What is the time Complexity of remove method of a Set in Java? I know in **ArrayList** the time complexity for remove method is **O(n)**, but want to confirm that is it same for Sets also?

Comment: Did you search before posting ?

Comment: you could have got the answer from the first google search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the **underlying implementation** a remove in a List / Set can be `O(1)`, `O(n)` or `O(log n)` (or some other even bigger complexity for esoteric implementations).

`ArrayList` remove is `O(n)` on everything but the last element. Removing the last element in an `ArrayList` is `O(1)` (decrementing the size counter and setting the element to `null`).

Now you are asking about an interface (`Set`) which has at least two implementations (`TreeSet`, `HashSet`) which both offer a different time complexity for removal as would be the case for `LinkedList` in the List case (which e.g. has `O(1)` removal of the head).

The set interface doesn't guarantee an upper bound to the removal but any sane set implementation is at worst `O(log n)` I would suppose :)